# Punctuation: We promise [that] it's a big deal

Tags: punctuation, speech

I'm editing a marketing campaign. Out loud, one might say, "We promise it's a big deal." I believe there's an unspoken "that" in there: "We promise [that] it's a big deal." Would you punctuate the sentence differently with the missing word? My first instinct was no punctuation: "We promise it's a big deal." But on subsequent passes, it started to look more and more incorrect. It's very possible that I've gotten way too close to the words and can't see the logical, simple answer in front of me! Thanks for your help.

Comment: IMO, whether the punctuation is ok "as is" or needs something is entirely dependent on what kind of emphasis, if any, is used in the delivery of that statement.  Will the announcer say, "We promise!  It's a BIG deal!"  or just straightforward like "We promise it's a big deal"?

Comment: @FumbleFingers thanks! I didn't know how to phrase that question. The answers there were helpful.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

No comma is necessary. However, if you want to adde emphasis on promise, you could follow it with a comma. `We promise, it's a big deal.` which is in effect the same as "It's a big deal, we promise.`

Comment: The OP never mentions commas

Comment: @FumbleFingers Would you *punctuate* the sentence differently?

Comment: One might also write "We promise:  It's a big deal."

Comment: B..b...but, the OP never mentions *colons* /s ^o^

Comment: Unless the actual text following the word ***promise*** was effectively reported speech (and even then probably only if the grammatical subject was a relatively long term), I'd be unlikely to bother with any punctuation (and if I *did*, I'd probably go for @Hot Licks's colon). But so far as I can see OP just needs help understanding how ***that*** works in such constructions. And that's a duplicate that's been covered many times before on ELU.